# cannor resolve symbol "baidu" android studio

Tags: android, baidu

```
import com.baidu.android.pushservice.PushConstants;
import com.baidu.android.pushservice.PushManager;
```

I am unable to import the above libraries into my android application.
What dependencies should I add in the build.gradle in order to import them?

Comment: What IDE are you using? Android Studio?

Comment: You have the library as a `jar` file?

Comment: no. I dont have any jar files. how do I include "baidu" libraries. I used the code from another source, so I dont know the library locations

Comment: That means you have the source code of the libraries?

Comment: no! I dont have any source code for the libraries

Comment: This is the Baidu library you need to install - https://github.com/zhaiyuyong/baidu-push-demo.

Comment: If you need help with installing libraries, search on Google, plenty of tutorials available...